# PHP compress files into zip

Tags: php, html, compression, mp3

Hello there
okay so this is the deal i have a folder where my mp3 files are stored for single download, and now i want a feature where you can download all the mp3s at once in a zipped folder. Is it possible to zip all the files from that folder using php ( or anything really but if not PHP then please explain thoroughly) or would i have to just re-upload all the mp3s again in zipped format?

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Have you checked http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open file, write to file, save file as a zip and stream to user for download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286639/open-file-write-to-file-save-file-as-a-zip-and-stream-to-user-for-download) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953996/php-zip-3-small-text-files-and-force-download and others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to demonstrate use of the undocumented addGlob() method of the zipArchive class:

```
$zipFile = dirname(__FILE__)."/myMP3s.zip";
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE))
    die("Failed to create archive\n");

$zipArchive->addGlob(dirname(__FILE__)."/*.mp3");
if (!$zipArchive->status == ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OK)
    echo "Failed to write local files to zip\n";

$zipArchive->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several PHP [libraries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php) for compression. Have you tried them?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Mark Baker's example looks good, read up if you want to learn or need something more specific.