# Incorrect zip folder structure in php

Tags: php, yii

I am creating zip file using ZipArchive in php. code-

```
$path = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/quickshopimages/productimage/';
$zip =new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('test.zip', ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE);
$iterator=new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
foreach($iterator as $file) 
{
  if($file->isDir())   
  {
   echo strtoupper($file->getRealpath()), PHP_EOL.'<br/>';$file .'/');
   $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace(strtoupper($file->getRealpath()) . '/', '', 
   $file . '/'));
  }
 else
 {
  $zip->addFile($file);
 }
}
$zip->close();
```

But here problem is that when I create zip its folder structure sets as

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\quickshop\trunk\quickshopimages\productimage\male\shirts\Ethnic\1

and my main root directory is from "productimage\male\shirts\Ethnic\1". So, how can start zip folder from "productimage" as root here?

Thanks in advance and sorry for English

Comment: Do you actually take a look at your question? I think it can benefit from some formatting...

Comment: take a look at this, http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

Answer (score 0):

See the answers below, your problem seems to comes from your usage of $zip->addFile($file);, with no second parameter.

[php creating zips without path to files inside the zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993105/php-creating-zips-without-path-to-files-inside-the-zip)

Answer (score 0):

Yii has a zip extension.
[yii zip ext.](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ezip/)

```
$zip = Yii::app()->zip;
$zip->makeZip('./','./toto.zip'); // make an ZIP archive 
$zip->extractZip('./toto.zip', './1/'); // extract Zip arc.
```