# Add files to the zip

Tags: php

The below code creates a zip file in my own PHP directory, but how can I specify the output folder?

Also, when we extract the zip file, it contains the folder structure of files; how can I prevent this?

```
$zip=new ZipArchive;
$destination1="C:/testfolder/destination/*.*";
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach (glob($destination1) as $filename)
{
    $zip->addFile($filename);
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: zip file should be present in new directory. How to specify the new output directory for zip files???

Comment: I got that too... if i extract the zip files it contains c folder then test folder then destination folderthen files... my expected output is zipfile should contain only files

Comment: Do you want to force users to expand the ZIP in a given directory in their computers? (as about the folder structure, just read the documentation for [ZipArchive::addFile()](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php)).

Comment: In PHP, you want to visit [PHPNet](http://www.php.net/manual/) for all PHP documentation. You've lot of sample for using ZipArchive Class [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php). You want to read all user's comment. Globaly, I found all Answers with comments.

Comment: Your second question (regarding removal of dirnames) might have been answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993105/php-creating-zips-without-path-to-files-inside-the-zip

Comment: Although you really are correct this isn't an answer, but a comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
/* creates a compressed zip file */
function create_zip($files = array(),$destination = '',$overwrite = false) {
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if(file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) { return false; }
    //vars
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if(is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach($files as $file) {
            //make sure the file exists
            if(file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    //if we have good files...
    if(count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($destination,$overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        //add the files
        foreach($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file,$file);
        }
        //debug
        //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;

        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();

        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($destination);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Sample Usage

```
$files_to_zip = array(
    'preload-images/1.jpg',
    'preload-images/2.jpg',
    'preload-images/5.jpg',
    'kwicks/ringo.gif',
    'rod.jpg',
    'reddit.gif'
);
//if true, good; if false, zip creation failed
$result = create_zip($files_to_zip,'my-archive.zip');
```

good luck