# How to add a file from web to a zip file on my server using php?

Tags: php, upload, zip, cloud

Imagine there is a picture at http://example.com/icon.jpg and I want to add it to a zip file on my own sever named "Stack.zip" using php. This is my code, but it doesn't work.

```
$url="http://example.com/icon.jpg"
$zip = new ZipArchive;
echo $zip->open("Stack.zip");
$zip->addFile($url);
$zip->close();
```

*P.S.* I was able to do it with local files, but I had no success on doing it with internet addresses. So that's why I asked this question.

Comment: What's your afford so far? Have you looked it up on the internet? For example [the php manuals](http://php.net/manual/de/book.zip.php)

Comment: @AndreasLackner Yes, and I was successful on doing it with local files, but not with addresses from the internet.

Comment: Then just store the file in a local temp-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php
(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7, PECL zip >= 1.1.0)

This assumes you want to add to an existing zip file on your server.

```
$url = 'https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/hubfs/logo-so-color.png?t=1499443352566';
$local_path = '/your/local/folder/';
$img = 'icon.jpg';
file_put_contents($local_path.$img, file_get_contents($url));

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($local_path.'Stack.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile($local_path.$img, $img);
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

If you want to keep the same folder structure as the original source file, change this line ..

```
$zip->addFile($local_path.$img, $img);
```

...to this...

```
$zip->addFile($local_path.$img);
```

If you want the same script to create the zip, you can find a PHP function here: [Add files to the zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856887/add-files-to-the-zip)