# create zip file inside a folder but without folder inside that zip

Tags: php, file, zip

```
$File = "images/files.txt";

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./images/files.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

$zip->addFile("$File");
$zip->close();
```

This code creates a files.zip file inside 'images' folder, if I open that zip file, 'images' folder is there too. I don't want folder 'images' to be there. But only the 'files.txt' file(located inside images folder) needs to be there.

Files structure:

- zip.php
- images

  - files.txt

How can I do that?

Comment: opendir() to be located in `images` and then use $filename only for files.zip

Comment: I've tested your code. It works as expected. No image folder inside that zip

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: [php-creating-zips-without-path-to-files-inside-the-zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993105/php-creating-zips-without-path-to-files-inside-the-zip?rq=1)

Comment: @RoyalBg please give me a code for that, I couldn't

Comment: @hek2mgl yes, but the folder 'images' will be inside that zip too and I don't want that

Comment: @redone Did you read my last comment?

Comment: Well, there's a whole topic posted here. Maybe better solution than mine. But if you insist I will try to code my solution

Comment: @RoyalBg that opendir() stuff is bollocks (and not helpful, srry)

Comment: @redone remove the existing zip from filesystem. I guess if you run the script again the zip will not being created. That's because `zip->open()` will create only a temporary archive. The real work is done by `zip->close()`. If `close()` fails, the temporary zip will be removed, if it succeeds it will be renamed to it's final name. Check the return value of `close()`

Comment: I removed and tried again but happened the same again.

Comment: @hek2mgl I have 'files.txt' inside 'images' folder, that's why it's happening.

Comment: Maybe you posted here not exactly the same code that you have? Because (as said @hek2mgl) this code is working fine.

Comment: one question for you guys.. how can I add multiple files in that zip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> @hek2mgl I have 'files.txt' inside 'images' folder, that's why it's happening

Then your code will not work at all as the path to `$File` is wrong. Use this:

```
$File = "images/files.txt";

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./images/files.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}

// use the second parameter of addFile(). It will give the file
// a new name inside the archive. basename() returns the filename
// from a given path
$zip->addFile("$File", basename($File));

if(!$zip->close()) {
    die('failed to create archive');
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that's the directory I'm giving to $File and it's not working

Comment: @redone so what now? have you tested **my** example? **my** example means, copy the code from my answer and execute it - **unchanged**!