# Creating a zip file in a specific path without any subfolders

Tags: php, zip

I need to create a Zip file in a specific file path without any sub folders created inside it,
here is my code :

```
$files = array('article/includes/pdfFiles/file1.txt','article/includes/pdfFiles/file2.txt');
$zipname = 'article/includes/pdfFiles/file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

I need the file.zip to be created in the path 'assets/uploads/pdfFiles' in this folder, its been created but the problem is inside the zip file these folders exits: assets/uploads/pdfFiles
How can I create the zip file without these folders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php creating zips without path to files inside the zip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993105/php-creating-zips-without-path-to-files-inside-the-zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code above doesn't work because you don't show the contents of *$fileNames* but I am assuming it is something like:

```
array('assets/uploads/pdfFiles/file1.txt','assets/uploads/pdfFiles/file2.txt',...)
```

When you add to the zip do this:

```
foreach ($fileNames as $fullpath) {
    // pull just the file name from the path
    $filename = substr($fullpath, strrpos($fullpath, '/')+1);
    $zip->addFile($fullpath,$filename);
}
```