# ZipArchive PHP adding only files without directories from the whole path

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Fellow coders:

Hate to ask this question, as it was, I belive correctly answered two times:

1. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993105/php-creating-zips-without-path-to-files-inside-the-zip)
2. [And here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988496/how-to-add-a-txt-file-and-create-a-zip-in-php/3989210#3989210)

So the problem is: when unzipping the downloaded 'file.zip', after unzipping, it contains all the folders from the path, even tough I specified the local file in the addFile function. I'd like the zip file not to contain any subfolder, just files.

```
$zipname = str_replace(' ', '_', $obj['Name']) . '.zip';

$zip = new ZipArchive();

$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // $file looks like this: webroot/uploadify/files/file.jpg
    $zip->addFile($file, pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME));
}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header("Content-type: application/zip");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $zipname);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));

readfile($zipname);
```

Can anyone see what's the problem with this code?

Additional info:

I, ofc, use paths relative to the webroot, but the folder hierarchy in the extracted folder after:
extract to file -> 'my_file.zip' 
is **C->xampp->htdocs->my_cakephp_web_app->app->webroot->files** which is not exactly what I wanted to achieve :)

PHP 5.4.4

Windows XP, XAMPP

**EDIT**

Tried using the http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/ library and had the same problem.
Also on my home PC ( win7 ) this code worked well.

**This brings up a question:** Are there any settings I should meet that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 4):

I have run your code and it works as expected. So there are 3 things that could be going wrong from what I can see.

Try using these flags in case an old file still exists and it is not being overwritten (it is not clear what $obj['Name'] is set to )
If you read the comments in the php manual, there are varying degrees of success using ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE vs ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE, so perhaps using both will work.

```
$zip->open( $zipname, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE );
```

Pathinfo could be failing and returning the whole path or null for some reason

Is it possible to do a var_dump on the pathinfo output, just to confirm it is what you expect it to be?

```
foreach ( $files as $file )
{
     var_dump(pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME ));

    // $file looks like this: webroot/uploadify/files/file.jpg
    // $zip->addFile( $file, pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME ) );
}
```

Maybe there is a bug with your os/php version with addFile function (unlikely, grasping at straws here as i can't see any other explanation)

Comment: If you've got time, take a look at my answer please and let me know why it's working :)

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 5.3 this should do it:

```
$phar = new PharData('file.zip');

// add all files in the folder, only include files with extensions
$phar->buildFromDirectory('/directory', '~[.][0-9a-z]+$~i');
```

You could also use [`PharData::buildFromIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/phardata.buildfromiterator.php) with the `LEAVES_ONLY` flag.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code like this:

`$phar = new PharData( 'tmp_zips/file.zip' );
$phar->buildFromDirectory( '/uploadify/files/test1', '~[.][0-9a-z]+$~i' );`

I got this error:

`RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(/uploadify/files/test1,/uploadify/files/test1): The system cannot find the path specified. (code: 3)`

Comment: @IgorLacik: Seems to suggest that you mistyped your path.

Answer (score 2):

You need to test each file to see if it's a file (rather than a directory, symlink, etc):

```
foreach ( $files as $file )
{
    if(filetype($file) == 'file') {
        $zip->addFile( $file, pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME ) );
    }
}
```

This is using [filetype](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filetype.php), but you could also use [is_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php).

Comment: If you've got time, take a look at my answer please and let me know why it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea why this is working :)

I'd actually believe, that my PC entered a Skynet mode and got the addFile method to work somehow :)

Anyone who can plausibly explain what happened will get the +50 bonus :)

```
    $zipname = str_replace( ' ', '_', $obj['Name'] ) . '.zip';

    $zip = new ZipArchive;

    $zip->open( $zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE );

    foreach ( $files as $file )
    {
        // the str_replace made it work???
        $zip->addFile( str_replace( '/webroot', '', getcwd() . '/' . $file ), pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_BASENAME ) );
    }

    $zip->close();

    header("Content-type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $zipname);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize( $zipname ));

    readfile( $zipname );
```

**EDIT:**

Also, after having some more trouble with temporary files not deleteing themselves, I switched to http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/, which works well.

Also, Alix Axel mentioned PharData below, given the amount of score he's earned here, I'm considering his approach as well..

Comment: Just curious as to what the value of getcwd() is. It looks like you are translating a relative path to an absolute path.

Comment: This is from the 1st comment on the php manual for $zip->addFile.      Beware: calling $zip->addFile() on a file that doesn't exist will succeed and return TRUE, delaying the failure until you make the final $zip->close() call, which will return FALSE and potentially leave you scratching your head.

If you're adding multiple files to a zip and your $zip->close() call is returning FALSE, ensure that all the files you added actually exist.

It's also a good idea to check each file with file_exists() or is_readable() before calling $zip->addFile() on it.

Comment: getcwd() returns "C:\xampp\htdocs\test_tool\app\webroot".

Also read that comment and figured that since the zip archive is being created, it works ( should've printed the $zip->close() out, will know next time when having trouble ).